# Training a classifier to find a subset of some data

Tags: classification

I have a dataset of individuals which can be split into two groups: those that have performed an action (group 1) and those that haven't (group 0). For each individual I have a large number of features, some of which can be used to attempt to distinguish between the two groups (including a boolean corresponding to the action I'm interested in).

What I would like to do is to find the subset of group 0 that look the most likely to perform this action, thus moving from group 0 to group 1.

It isn't clear to me what is the best approach to this at all - I started by training a classifier on a subset of my data to distinguish between the two groups. This classifier was then be run over the remainder of the data and I looked at those members of group 0 that were misclassified as being in group 1 (or for which the classifier had a lower probability for their membership in group 0), but this really don't seem to be a sensible approach. Obviously part of what this will be doing is finding a way to reject the 'group 1-like' members of group 0, and these are the individuals I'm really interested in.

Are there any better alternatives? Really what I want is to train a model to find the 'group 1-like' entries in the entire dataset.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably moved with your life, but one class classification or P-U learning would be suitable for your problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification